# Как в golang проверить реализовывет ли поле структуры определенный интерфейс?

Tags: golang, рефлексия, метапрограммирование

Как в golang проверить реализовывет ли поле структуры определенный интерфейс ? Может можно через reflect? Вот пример, как мне проверить что поле е структуры Test реализовывет интерфейс Exemple?

```
type Example interface {
    String() string
}

type ExampleImpl struct {
    
}

func (e ExampleImpl) String() string {
    return "Exemple"
}

type Test struct {
    e ExampleImpl
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рантайме можно сделать проверку таким образом:

```
_, ok = interface{}(ExampleImpl{}).(Example)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/YY1vBl-xvXq

Answer (score 0):

```
var _ Example = (*ExampleImpl)(nil)
```

Если кратко, то это типизированный nil, проверяет реализацию интерфейса, самому интерфейсу. Подробности в [докладе](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Comment: мне нужно делать это в процессе выполнения программы, а не для проверки структуры